# Android button latency?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been working on a drum machine app, and the latency between the time you press the button and the time the sound plays is unbearable. I have seen some people use multitouch and gridviews, and make several buttons able to be pressed at the same time, but I honestly have no knowledge of those. How could I set up multitouch or gridviews to reduce the latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the *multitouchable buttons* are a very custom implementation. You won't ever be able to touch two ordinary buttons simultaneosly, since they are made for single touch and are based on focus gain etc.

Here's my idea behind a multitouchable implementation:
You create a very custom view which will draw all buttons you need. This view should override `onTouchEvent` and react on multitouch. I never tried that, but this is the only option I can think of.